# Redirect_to(:back) in Rails after saving form to database causing routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails from from scratch (without the use of Scaffold for the first time) to do a simple thing: submit to a database the username and a post.

To do that, in my Stories Controller, I have set up a create method:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.where(slug: params[:id]).all
  end

  def create
    @comments = Comment.new(params[:comments])
    @comments.save
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
end
```

Then, in my view, I have this form in my Stories view:

```
<%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :post %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>
  <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

What's weird is that when I click save, it fails to save to the table **and** has a routing error:

> `No route matches [POST] "/stories"`

**Troubleshooting**

1. First off, I want to redirect back to the same page I was on, which has a URL like `http://localhost:3000/stories?id=example-post-slug`. I thought the routing error was weird, because shouldn't it just go back based on my controller code?
2. I also thought my `routes.rb` file could be an issue, but I have added it as a resource as other answers have suggested:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  get "stories" => "stories#index", as: :stories
  ....
end
```

Thus, I am confused. Why am I having a routing issue when I have defined the create method, added the `Comments` table as a resource, and I have chosen a redirect in my controller?

Comment: Your controller seems not ok. `create` method should be out of `stories` method

Comment: Good tip. To fix this, I created a Stories controller, added a Stories folder for the `index.html.erb` view, and then updated the Routes file. These edits are now reflected in the code above; however, the error that I am receiving remains the same.

Comment: I cant see `resources :stories` anywhere in ur routes.